# Exception: Index `node_auto_index` does not exist

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I am creating a graph database in a java application using Neo4j. But when I run a cypher query it gives me the exception "Index `node_auto_index` does not exist".

I am new to Neo4j and already looked for some similar questions but didn't find any solution yet.

Here's the configuration code for setting auto indexed enabled

```
database.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().setEnabled(true);
database.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().startAutoIndexingProperty("value");
```

And Here's my query:

```
Query = "START a=node:node_auto_index(value={word}) "
          + "WHERE HAS(a.type) "
          + "SET a.type = {type} "
          + "RETURN a.value";
```

Comment: Have you restarted your Neo4j instance after the node auto indexer configuration changes?

Comment: Yes, I did restart but still the same exception

Answer (score 0):

If you use Neo4j embedded, you have to either call the auto-index code in your startup code or you have to pass in the appropriate config to the database factory method.

This setting is not stored in the database.

Also if you are just starting with Neo4j use 2.0.3 and automatic indexes.

see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html

Comment: I am doing the same in the first two lines of my code. Or is there anything I am missing! ?

Comment: Here's my code:
if (database == null) 
{ database = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("/neo4j-1.9.2/data/graph.db");
database.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().setEnabled(true);   database.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().startAutoIndexingProperty("value");
}
return database;